# Writing to a dictionary from several view controllers

Tags: ios

I'm stuck with a problem which I'm not sure how to solve. I have several view controllers which follows each other as the user populates them with data.
Before changing views I use an alert controller for the user to confirm correctness of data before pushing to the next view controller. However, here I need to capture the data but I'm only writing the data to Realm once all the data is gathered.
My question is this; how do I temporarily keep this data (and use some of them forward) until it's time to write to the database?

Comment: You pass the realm object across the view controllers and set the data you want in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a property in each of the view controllers.

*in the .h file, under `interface`*

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) MyRealmObject *realmObject;
```

*in the .m file, under `implementation`*

```
@synthesize realmObject
```

Then, in your `prepareForSegue` method, you populate the copy local to your view controller, instantiate the destination view controller, and then pass the local Realm object into the property of the destination view controller.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SegueName"]) {
        DestinationViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.realmObject = self.realmObject;
    }
}
```

This will pass a copy of your existing realm object to the next view controller